# Can I mount a light switch and power on the outside of a wall?

Tags: electrical, switch

My garage has no permanent light fixtures. The only thing there is an old chandelier hung from a hook in the ceiling and plugged into the wall.

To turn it on I have to use a pull chain which is in an awkward position that I don't like at all. Just inside the garage on the wall are my garage door switches. I don't really want to do everything that would be required to put a switch in the wall there, so I was wondering if it would be possible (and within code - I live in Arkansas if that matters) to mount a light switch to the wall that powered... something.

Presumably an outlet that I mounted elsewhere, such as the ceiling (we actually already have a ceiling mounted electrical box that the garage door openers are plugged into). Then I could plug the lamp into that outlet and just flip the switch in the garage which would be far more convenient.

Comment: Have you worked with conduit before, or are you willing to acquire the skillset to do so? (i.e. bending the stuff, pulling wires through it)

Comment: Not before, but I'm totally open to learn

Comment: There is always the PVC conduit route. No bending metal just buy the parts and glue together. Schedule 80 will be needed if exposed on the surface of the walls.

Comment: Run a piece of string from the pull chain over to the door, and thru a 90° pvc pipe elbow so it hangs down right near where you come in. Tie a 1" nut to the end of the string as a weight. Pull down for on, pull down for off. No new electrical wiring needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there's any code stating you need to put electrical wiring, outlets, switches *inside* the wall as long as they are of the correct type. Use conduit for both safety and asthetics.

It would violate codes to go the other way, and say run standard extension power cables *inside* the walls though.

Simple example:
[How to](http://www.familyhandyman.com/electrical/wiring/how-to-install-surface-mounted-wiring-and-conduit/view-all)

Comment: Surface metal or nonmetallic raceway is also an option here